# i want to repeat a certain if statement if necessary in python

Tags: python, command, keyword

```
elif opt==2:
    nitem=str(input('enter the porduct name'))
    nitemc=int(input('enter the item code'))
    nstkq=int(input('enter stock qty'))
    nitemtyp=str(input('enter item type'))
    b={'itemname':nitem,'itemcode':nitemc,'item-type':nitemtyp,'stock':nstkq}
    stock=stock.append(b ,ignore_index=True)
    x=str(input('do you want to add another one? \n "y" for yes "n" for no' ))
    if x=='y':
        <to repeat>
```

what code should i use to make the code repeat again as much the time the user asks for?

hope i will get help thankyou!!!!!!!

Comment: How about a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
elif opt==2:
    while True:
        nitem=str(input('enter the porduct name'))
        nitemc=int(input('enter the item code'))
        nstkq=int(input('enter stock qty'))
        nitemtyp=str(input('enter item type'))
        b={'itemname':nitem,'itemcode':nitemc,'item-type':nitemtyp,'stock':nstkq}
        stock=stock.append(b ,ignore_index=True)
        x=str(input('do you want to add another one? \n "y" for yes "n" for no' ))
        if x=='n':
            break
```